# How to fix Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = 'images.zip' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)?

Tags: flutter, dart, file, zip, archive

I'm trying to write code in Dart using the Archive library to package images a user uploads into a Zip File and then upload that zip file to Firebase. However, my compiler is saying that it cannot open the file. Here is my code:

```
Future<String> zipImages(List<FFUploadedFile> images) async {
  final archive = Archive();

  for (for final image in images; i++) {
    print(image);
    Uint8List? bytes = image.bytes;

    Future<File> createTemporaryFile(Uint8List? bytes, int num) async {
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      String tempPath = tempDir.path + '/image';
      File tempFile = File(tempPath);
      await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes as List<int>);
      return tempFile;
    }

    File tempFile = await createTemporaryFile(bytes, i);

    final bytesFromFile = await tempFile.readAsBytes();
    final archiveFile =
        ArchiveFile('uploadedImages', bytesFromFile.length, bytesFromFile);

    archive.addFile(archiveFile);
  }

  final zipEncoder = ZipEncoder();
  final encodedArchive = zipEncoder.encode(archive);
  if (encodedArchive == null) return "error";

  final zipFile = await File('images.zip').writeAsBytes(encodedArchive);
```

Do I need to change some access files elsewhere? Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to have a few issues.

It appears that the loop iterating through the images might have a syntax error, and the function `createTemporaryFile` is being defined inside the loop, which is unnecessary and might cause problems.

Try use bellow modified code segment,

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';

Future<String> zipImages(List<FFUploadedFile> images) async {
  final archive = Archive();
  int i = 0;

  for (final image in images) {
    Uint8List? bytes = image.bytes;

    // Creating a temporary file for each image
    File tempFile = await createTemporaryFile(bytes, i);
    final bytesFromFile = await tempFile.readAsBytes();
    final archiveFile =
        ArchiveFile('uploadedImage$i', bytesFromFile.length, bytesFromFile);

    archive.addFile(archiveFile);
    i++;
  }

  final zipEncoder = ZipEncoder();
  final encodedArchive = zipEncoder.encode(archive);
  if (encodedArchive == null) return "error";

  final zipFile = await File('images.zip').writeAsBytes(encodedArchive);
  return zipFile.path; // Returning the path to the created zip file
}

Future<File> createTemporaryFile(Uint8List? bytes, int num) async {
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = '${tempDir.path}/image$num'; // Unique name for each image
  File tempFile = File(tempPath);
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes!);
  return tempFile;
}
```

Changes,

1.Moved the definition of `createTemporaryFile` function outside of the loop.

2.Changed the loop iteration to a more conventional format.

3.Used a unique name for each image file inside the temporary directory.

4.Added a return statement to return the path to the created zip file in the `zipImages` function.

**Make sure you have proper error handling and necessary imports `(import 'dart:io';, import 'dart:typed_data';, and package:archive/archive.dart)`.**

**Also, ensure the `FFUploadedFile` class or relevant data structure is correctly defined and that the permissions for accessing directories/files are granted.**